# using javascript to replace onpage javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm fairly new to javascript so please go easy on me,

I have this code on a webpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> bb1 = "oldcode"; bb2 = "morecodehgere"; bb3 = 160000;</script>
```

I want to replace 1% of all page loads **oldcode** to **newcode**

There are multiple instances of this code on the same page and I want to replace them all.

```
window.onload = replaceScript;
function replaceScript() {
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
var toReplace = 'oldcode';
var replaceWith ='newcode';
if randomNumber == 1 {
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/toReplace/g, replaceWith);
 }
}
```

This is the current code I've got but it doesn't work.

Is javascript the bast way to achieve what I'm looking to do? If so whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you please explain me why your main logic is based on a random number?

Comment: @tkr_in I'm struggling to understand the question but I think the OP wants to run this bizarre script on 1 in a 100 page loads.

Comment: @Moob yes that's correct.

Comment: If you want to run it one in a hundred more or less randomly, then `Math.random() > 0.99` should do.

Comment: @RobG Arr yes, that makes much more sense. Unfortunately even without it being random the script still doesn't work.

Comment: I really suggest you to include "old" or "new" script basing on your random-chance number on SERVER side. Or, at least, by appending new <script> tag from client. Your current approach is too obscure.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression literal:

```
/toReplace/g
```

will create a regular expression object that matches the string "toReplace". If you want to create a regular expression to match the  (string) value of the variable `toReplace`, you must use the RegExp constructor:

```
var re = new RegExp(toReplace, 'g');
```

It is not a good idea to replace the innerHTML of the body with a copy of itself. The innerHTML property doesn't necessarily reflect all the nuances of the DOM and will not include things like dynamically added listeners. It also varies from browser to browser.

Using a regular expression to replace parts of innerHTML is almost certain to produce unpredictable results, it may work well on trivial pages but will not be reliable on complex pages.